# Different type of data when comparing SQLite vs MySQL query result in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I'm looking for an explanation of the result of the following query with Active Record:

```
date_range = (Date.today - 7)..(Time.now.to_datetime)
r = Report.find(:all, :conditions => {:created_at => date_range},
                      :group => 'date(created_at)',
                      :select => 'date(created_at) as day, count(id) as counter')
```

Basically I'm just counting the results in a table "reports," but I got different types of values for the named field "counter", array of double quote strings vs array of only numbers.

### MySQL

If using MySQL,

```
r.map(&:counter)
```

returns:
**=> ["3", "3", "5", "4", "4"]**

### SQLite

If using SQLite,

```
r.map(&:counter)
```

returns:
**=> [3, 3, 5, 4, 4]**

Is it correct that MySQL returns the numbers with quotes (Strings) and SQLite numbers?
I expected that both return just integers. Or am I missing some configuration with on MySQL side?

**Edit:**
Just in case, both DBs where created using normal migrations, so all fields are equivalent types.

Comment: I'm presuming that in the MySQL database it's stored as an integer rather than string?

Comment: Just in case I checked again, "id" is as usual integer in both cases. And count(id) isn't supposed to give you just a number...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the SQLite ActiveRecord adapter.

When you are synthesizing new column values using "SELECT expr AS col_name" col_name is cast to a String instead of the proper data type (int in this case).

See related Rails bug ticket: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/4544-rails3-activerecord-sqlite3-lost-column-type-when-using-views#ticket-4544-2

Apparently SQLite can't return proper column type values for views, which is the mechanism used when you're synthesizing attributes like this.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue using the underlying connection to execute my SQL statements.

I have noticed, however, that if you are using binds in exec_sql statement, the data types come back as expected.

E.g.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_sql("select * from users where id = 35")
```

results in

> ActiveRecord::Result:0x7fa2c6ede200 @columns=["id", "name"], @hash_rows=nil, @rows=[["35", "FOO"]]

However,

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_sql("select * from users where id = ?", nil, [[nil,35]])
```

results in

> ActiveRecord::Result:0x7fa2c6ede200 @columns=["id", "name"],
>   @hash_rows=nil, @rows=[[35, "FOO"]]

Note that datatype of 35 is integer! 
Hope that helps.